# multistep checkout in ubercart 2.4

Tags: php, drupal-6, content-management-system, ubercart

Is there any option to create multistep checkout in ubercart 2.4? I mean to say if I want 4step checkout process, then is it possible in ubercart?

Comment: Is it possible? if yes the say me yes and how, otherwise say no.

Answer (score 1):

I was also recently surprised by the difficulty of this task.

The [consensus](http://drupal.org/node/733170) is that the task would be a very major undertaking to modify the ubercart core forms.  Doesn't seem likely anyone will do this anytime soon and it would be difficult to upgrade after major core modifications.

Best option seems to be to leave the checkout form (server-side) intact and build a tabbed/multistep wizard style deal w/ javascript.  Try http://rubencausyn.be/2011/08/ubercart-checkout-tabs/ for starters...